# select QString which is added to QcomboBox by setEditText(QString) method

Tags: qt, qcombobox

how to select a text which I have add to my QComboBox by comboBox->setEditText(someString). I want my text to be appeared by "selecting all the text" in combobox.

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <QLineEdit>
....
ui->comboBox->lineEdit()->selectAll();`

If I understood question.